# Проверить входит ли точка в заштрихованую область

Tags: c++

Вот рисунок, помогите сложить условие.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое простое - это проверить что точка входит в один из секторов: `|y| > |x|`,
а затем проверить что `|y| < 1`.

```
return fabs(x) < fabs(y) && fabs(y) < 1;
```

График на [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fabs%28x%29+%3C+fabs%28y%29+%26%26+fabs%28y%29+%3C+1).

Answer (score 1):

Данную область можно разбить на 2, условно пусть это будет верхний треугольник (`top_triangle`) и нижний треугольник (`bottom_triangle`). Далее, нужно проверить, входит ли точка в один из них. Для этого существует не один алгоритм, но я приведу самый простой, первый, что приходит в голову: проверяем, находится ли точка по нужную сторону от прямых, которые ограничивают треугольник:

```
bool check_entry(double x, double y) {
    bool top_triangle = (y <= 1.) && (y >= x) && (y >= -x);
    bool bottom_triangle = (y >= -1.) && (y <= x) && (y <= -x);
    return top_triangle || bottom_triangle;
}
```